# Java button event handler won't resolve

Tags: java, event-handling, awt

I am trying to set up an even handler on my GUI. However, when I declare the class and then call it on the button it cannot be resolved?

```
btnHigher = new JButton("Higher");
    btnHigher.setBounds(190, 110, 75, 50);
    btnHigher.addActionListener(new HigherHandler());
    panel.add(btnHigher);
```

Handler class:
    class HigherHandler implements ActionListener{

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    }
```

It just throws an error:
HigherHandler cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: have you used the `import` statement for `HigherHandler`?

Comment: I have imported Action Event and ActionListener.

Comment: Be careful about wording. "Throwing" in a java context ... means: while your program is **running** some kind of exception is thrown. Whereas in your case, you are probably talking about a compiler error message. Those are two really different things. And for your problem itself: probably the compiler message tells you all you need to know: its about a type that is not known. So, turn to that part of your book or tutorial that you are following that explains that you.

Comment: I am following a book. However, I have already implemented one action listener and it works fine. It when I start to add multiple listeners it produces and error. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btnHigher = new JButton("Higher");
    btnHigher.setBounds(190, 110, 75, 50);
    btnHigher.addActionListener(new HigherHandler());
    panel.add(btnHigher);
```

The following line can be written as this instead of making a new class.

```
 btnHigher.addActionListener(new HigherHandler(){
       // it will ask you to add implemented method here which is action performed method.
```

});